# PHP/Html - Change link in "href" according to the file path

Tags: php, html, href

I created a php file where I imported my navbar which I created in a different file. The problem being that the href of the links change depending on the files and I don't see how to fix that.

For example, I have a file 1 in folder 1 where I imported my header with a link that goes to a file 2 in folder 2. If I create a file 3 with a different path, the link will no longer be valid to the file and I don't see how I can fix this.

In my navbar file :

`<div class="d-none d-md-inline-block d-lg-none">  <a href="test.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-md-4">Se connecter</button></a>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-md-4">S'inscrire</button> </div>`

In my file :

`<?php include "../header/header.html"; ?>`

The path to test.php will vary depending on which file I import it to.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `/` at the beginning of the **href**. This will direct the link to the root (beginning) of your server path. For example, if **test.html** is in your parent folder, use `href="/test.html"`.

Comment: Thank's !

can I also use `dirname(__DIR__)` ?

Comment: I think you can.

Comment: Thank you very much !